# Linking to ROOT files in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, root-framework

I need to link to the .so files and headers found in /root/lib and /root/include in a project in xcode 3.2.6. ROOT is an analysis framework from CERN.

There is a utility root-config, that will return all the libraries necessary, I can compile on the command line using:

```
CFLAGS = `root-config --cflags`
GLIBS = `root-config --glibs`

test : main.cpp main.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(GLIBS) -g -Wall main.cpp -02 -o test
```

Program runs fine with no bugs. But, I want to use xcode for the whole project, but can't get it to either

A: use this utility

or

B: search the right paths to the .so files. I have included /root/lib and /root/include in the build variables header_search_paths and library_search_paths under the build settings. I then actually type in the files I need into the other_linker_flags like so:
`-llibTree -llibHist -llibRIO -llibCint -llibCore`

xcode returns the message:

```
ld: library not found for -llibTree
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Does anybody know whats going on? Can xCode compile .so files? Is there some other issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ROOT. To link against a library named `libSomething.so` in your library search path you can use a linker flag `-lSomething`. You want to link against e.g. `libTree.so`, so the correct flag to use would be `-lTree`, not `-llibTree` which would look for `liblibTree`.

Comment: My project links ok against libCling.so but throws `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libCling.so Reason: image not found` any ideas?